# Galaxy Note 2 shows no sim card after radio flash

Tags: sim-card, radio-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have the SGH-T889 (T-Mobile USA version of the Note 2). When I got my Galaxy Note 2, I loved the device, but disliked the software. So, I decided to flash CyanogenMod 10 build from the N7100 forums. Although many things worked, the radio did not work. So, I decided (in my infinite wisdom), to `dd` the radio from the Stock SGH-T889 T-Mobile rom to the /dev/block/mmcblk0p10 partition (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2039081).

This did not work, so I installed the stock SGH-T889 rom just to get it back to working order. However, my sim card was no longer being detected. I have tried flashing other roms to try and get the radio back, but alas all say that there is no sim card.

I realize I have probably permanently messed up my phone. Does anyone have any ideas or things to try to get it back to working order? I am out of things to try.

**UPDATE:** I have tried everything you guys have posted, and ended up sending it back to Samsung and get them to fix it under the warranty. I believe they replaced the whole motherboard, so I will never know exactly what the problem was. If you decide to send yours back, make sure to reset the binary counter that you see in download mode. There are guides around the Internet for this. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: How did you flash it back?  Have you tried Odin with repartitioning?

Comment: You could search the net for an original radio image for your device, and flash that the normal way. With some luck the Samsung service might provide you with that (in case you don't find it on the net).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I am pretty sure that I have flashed with Odin with the Re-Partition option checked, but I will try again tonight to make sure. I have found and flashed this modem zip with no luck: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1957380 (do 'modem' and 'radio' refer to the same thing in Android?)

Answer (score 1):

Get the ODIN package from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1969551). Then use ODIN to restore to "True" Factory Stock. This will put you back to stock (but will not reset your flash counter). Then from there you can start and use ODIN to root the device again, flash CWM and flash custom ROMs. The modem/radio you linked to should be the radio that you will want to flash if you flash an N7100 ROM. But, as you can see, I would stay away from ROMs that are not for the specific model. the T889 has a couple ROMs based on the stock N7105, but there have been changes (things like the radio) replaced with versions that are for the T889.

I eagerly wait for an AOSP build (specifically CM) for the T889, until then, I am running one based off the [N7105 with the Bullet Kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1982322) by cmenard. This kernel has the modules for CIFS support, which I use constantly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So I just read through threads and was able to fix the problem. I simply looked up my model number for the Galaxy Note 2 T-Mobibe version, and I discovered by flashing the stock modem kernel fixed my problem of no SIM card error.

Download the modem stock recovery [here](http://androtransfer.com/?developer=cmenard&folder=SGH-T889).

Answer (score 0):

Simply look for your model number. I have tried 10 different stock kernels before one of them worked. When you get the right stock kernel for your model, it will work.

Flash the kernel with Clockwork Recovery. If you don't have Clockwork Recovery, you can download it from Google Play, but your phone must be rooted.